# $f^{(133)}(0)$ where $f(x)=x^3\sin(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm solving the task $f^{(133)}(0)$ where $f(x)=x^3\sin(4x)$.

And by Leibniz theorem, it's only component, where $(x^3)^{(i)}$ is non-zero as $x=0$ is $\binom{133}{3}\cdot6\cdot\sin(4x)\cdot4^{130}$

So the answer is $0$. I'm right here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be neater if you take the power series of  sin(x).
As $$\sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k} \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}$$
So we have 
$$x^3 \sin(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+4}}{(2k+1)!}$$
As the 133 derivative at $0$ is the coefficient of $x^{133}$ times $133!$ it is $0$.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $x^3$ and $\sin(4x)$ are **odd** functions, so their product is an even function.

It is easy to show that the derivative of an even function is an odd function, and the derivative of an odd function is an even function. Thus the $133$-th derivative of an even function is an odd function.

Any odd function evaluated at $0$ is $0$.

**Remark:** The function $f(x)$ is an odd function if $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x$. The unction $f(x)$ is an even function if $f(-x)=f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: from where is the $\sin(4x)$?

Comment: The function in the title involves $\sin x$. In the body of the post, the function $\sin(4x)$ is used. So one or the other is a typo. I chose $x^3\sin(4x)$. If the intended function is $x^3\sin x$, the argument is the same.